# How to fix the coding error 'input string was not in a correct format'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: the error message when i launch my program]

Here are the full details of my code:

```cs
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Sales> sales = new List<Sales>();
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadCSV();
            bs.DataSource = sales;
            dgvSales.DataSource = bs;
        }
    
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    
        }
    
        private void LoadCSV()
        {
            string filePath = @"c:\Users\demo\Task3_shop_data.csv";
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                List<string> items = line.Split(',').ToList();
                Sales s = new Sales();
                s.TextBook = items[0];
                s.Subject = items[1];
                s.Seller = items[2];
                s.Purchaser = items[3];
                s.purchasedPrice = float.Parse(items[4]);
                s.SalePrice = items[6];
                s.Rating = items[7];
                sales.Add(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my sales class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MichaelSACU301task3
{
internal class Sales
{
public string TextBook { get; set; }
public string Subject { get; set; }
public string Seller { get; set; }
public string Purchaser { get; set; }
public float purchasedPrice { get; set; }
public string SalePrice { get; set; }
public string Rating { get; set; }
}
}
```

I tried launching it but the error message keeps appearing can someone please help me fix this problem.

Comment: Most likely the string at `items[4]` can not be converted to float. For example there is a letter in the string, or a dash ... anything that is not decimal separator or latin digit. Use the watch debug window to see what string is in `items[4]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `float.TryParse` prior to assigning to `purchasedPrice` property, if the value can not be converted remember it in a list. In the example below the code to read file data is in a separate class which returns a list of sales and a list of int which is used to remember invalid lines where `purchasedPrice` data is invalid. You should also consider validating other data and also ensure proper amount of data after performing the line split.

```
public class FileOperations
{
    public static (List<Sales>, List<int>) LoadSalesFromFile()
    {
        List<Sales> sales = new List<Sales>();
        List<int> InvalidLine = new List<int>();

        string filePath = @"c:\Users\demo\Task3_shop_data.csv";
        List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

        for (int index = 0; index < lines.Count; index++)
        {
            var parts = lines[0].Split(',');
            // validate purchase price
            if (float.TryParse(parts[4], out var purchasePrice))
            {
                Sales s = new Sales();
                s.TextBook = parts[0];
                s.Subject = parts[1];
                s.Seller = parts[2];
                s.Purchaser = parts[3];
                s.purchasedPrice = purchasePrice;
                s.SalePrice = parts[6];
                s.Rating = parts[7];
                sales.Add(s);
            }
            else
            {
                // failed to convert purchase price
                InvalidLine.Add(index);
            }
        }

        return (sales, InvalidLine);
    }
}
```

Call the above code in your form

```
var (salesList, invalidLines) = FileOperations.LoadSalesFromFile();
if (invalidLines.Count > 0)
{
    // use to examine bad lines in file
}
else
{
    // uses sales list
}
```

Comment: hi where do I put the coding part that a you put below again                              var (salesList, invalidLines) = FileOperations.LoadSalesFromFile();
if (invalidLines.Count > 0)
{
    // use to examine bad lines in file
}
else
{
    // uses sales list

Comment: I would suggest in Form.Shown event as [shown here](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/windows-forms-csharp/tree/Version3/StackoverflowSalesFromFile)

Comment: @Crazygama Do you have time to come back and check the answer? If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark the reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

the error sis probably due the impossiability of `float.Parse()` parse the `items[4]` in float
you may track value of `items[4]` using brake point in VS